# SQL Server - Compare a 'CREATE TABLE' SQL script to a table definition using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to compare the script in a .sql file against a tables schema definition on a SQL Server database using C#. I also want to generate an alter table script based on the outcome of this comparison.

This can be done using Visual Studios 'Schema Compare' tool where a script gets generated afterwards. However it doesn't look like there is an API available for this?

So far I've tried using ScriptDom to read the .sql file but I cannot alter the script or compare this with the target table.

Any ideas what I could do here or any other languages that I could utilise?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to update a target sql server database based on changes made in a .sql file. The file will contain a create table sql statement. Ideally I need an alter table script generated from the comparison of the two

Comment: Right but why?? Do you not have any idea what changes might have been made? Why does the sql file not have logic to check for columns and such? It seems like something is missing here. You have a table and a create table statement. How do you end up in that position?

Comment: Because I'm pulling the .sql file out of TFS. I have a ssdt database project stored in TFS with changes constantly added to in and checked in. Now I'm trying to create a .net app to pull these changes out and push them to a target database

Comment: The changes to the DB are not controlled by the app? If they are then the changes should be pushed that way (like EF code first kind of thing), if they are controlled by another team then just make the changes to the DB and updated your model in the your app after the changes are made.

Comment: Who wrote the sql file and put it in TFS? How are they expecting the changes to be propagated?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to solve Brad. SSDT database projects store your sql server schema as files. I want to be able to push these out to the database by reading the sql file, comparing it to the target table, generating an alter table script then pushing this onto the target server

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just execute the script in a test database in order to create the table and then use a third party API like [xSQL Schema Compare SDK](http://www.xsql.com/products/sdk/sql_server_schema_compare/) to compare the two tables. xSQL Schema Compare will also generate the scripts to synchronize the two tables if it finds any differences. Hope this helps!